# Removing characters above X charCode in java

Tags: java, unicode, char

In Java, I can replace the character based on char code like this:

```
String text = "";
text = text.replaceAll(String.valueOf((char)61443), " ");
```

However, given a line of meaningless characters with different char code, what is the most efficient way to remove them? For example, the line below with many different char codes but all of them are above 60000. Is there anyway to remove all charcode above 60000 without looping through each character, or list down 60000 to 70000?

```

```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex with a ranged character class. Because you specified a range "to 70000", which is outside UTF-16, whose max is `\uFFFF` or 65535, you need the end of range to be a [*surrogate pair*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF), the max of which is `\uDBFF\uDFFF`, which decodes to `10FFFF` hex or 1114111 decimal:

```
text = text.replaceAll("[\uEA60-\uDBFF\uDFFF]+", "");
```

FYI `EA60` is `60000` in hexadecimal.

Note also the replacement with a *blank*, rather than a *space*, to *remove* them.

BTW, use `EA61` if you literally meant *above* 60000 and not 60000 *or above*.

Comment: @Michael doesn't Java store strings as UTF-16 anyway?

Comment: Then would `([\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDCFF])|[\uEA60-\uFFFF])+` work?

Comment: @Bohemian I have no way of testing right now, but I wonder if the regex would catch the "high surrogate followed by low surrogate" pair this way

Comment: @Michael I was wrong! I did more investigation and wrote some code and it can be done - see edit.

Comment: @julien.giband sorry - it can be done. see edit. you learn something every day...

Comment: Cool, didn't know java's regex engine supported it either.

Answer (score 3):

The regex in [Bohemian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67521520/1898563) is certainly more concise, but here's a way to do with a stream as well. Maybe it'll be useful to someone. Perhaps it's faster in certain cases, who knows.

If you want to remove any logical character above 65535 (you say in the question 60k-70k), then you need to consider code points.

This demonstrates a String containing the logical character ''. It may be invisible depending on the font, but it looks something like this:

[image: Indic Siyaq number]

```
final String newStr = "\uD9C0\uDC00".codePoints()
        .filter(chr -> chr <= 60_000 /*&& chr <= 70_000*/)
        .collect(
            StringBuilder::new,
            (sb, chr) -> sb.append((char) chr),
            StringBuilder::append
        )
        .toString();
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Output is an empty string.

Answer (score -2):

it is what you look at the screen, but in reality the symbols will be different
you need something like this `/^a-zA-Z0-9/`

```
text = text.replaceAll("^a-zA-Z0-9", " ");
```

Comment: This would replace everything that is not a letter or digit with a blank, including comma, punctuations, ... OP asked how to replace everything above a certain character code.